# scp backup a path with variables folders

Tags: backup, scp, schedule

I´m going to try explain my requirement for this backup. I supose it´s so easy but for me not because i don´t use to work with linux.

Scenario.
With a server linux via SCP i want to get from my firewall the daily logs. The firewall storage it´s logs in /StoneSoft/StoneGate/data/storage/Firewall/year2019/month09/day25/hour07/file_with_date.arch

I run a scp and i can copy withing problem. What I need is to program a bin sh script to copy daily the folder distinguishing the variables on the year, month, day and hour.

yearXXXX
monthXX
dayXX
hourXX

It´s this possible?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

save following text as a backup_arch.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

yearXXXX=${1:-2019}
monthXX=${2:-09}
dayXX=${3:-25}
hourXX=${4:-07}

destination=backup/$yearXXXX/$monthXX/$dayXX/$hourXX/
mkdir -p $destination

scp /StoneSoft/StoneGate/data/storage/Firewall/$yearXXXX/$monthXX/$dayXX/$hourXX/*.arch $destination
```

then

chmod a+x backup_arch.sh

then run it

./backup_arch.sh 2019 09 25 08

arguments are year month day hour

change destination= to the proper one.